# Jmeter distribute test: slave run test once and stopped (azure vms)

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to setup JMeter to run in distribute mode using Azure VMs.
I was able to setup the master-slave on two VMs, and kick off the test successfully.

However, the issue I have is the test plan I have was to run test in infinite loop for 300 seconds with 3 threads.  However, the slave VM only run a single thread once, then stopped.  checking server logs, and there is no exception or error, as if slave had "successfully completed".  on Master, it also completed after a single test run in slave.

Any suggestions on property or configuration that I may have incorrectly setup the cause the execution completed prematurely?    thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess what's wrong without seeing:

1. Your [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) configuration
2. Master log
3. Slaves logs

Looking into my crystal ball I can assume that your test is using some form of external data source, for example CSV file which is referenced by the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config). If this is the case - you need to copy your CSV file and any other dependent file(s) to all slaves as master only transfers .jmx test plan to slaves, anything else (configuration overrides, files to upload, data files, etc) is your responsibility.

More information: [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)